# Sybase: how to add a connection definition to ASE isql?

Tags: database

My knowledge of using sybase on windows is getting rusty...

I want to use the open source isql tool [ASE isql](http://code.google.com/p/aseisql/). When I tried to establish a connection to my sybase database, a 'Connection' dialog box pop up and ask for database/server/hostname information.

I think I need to put these information into a file which is equivalent to an interface file in unix world. Is it correct?

If so, where can I locate this file and what is the format? Any pointer is appreciated.

The target server is sybase 12.5

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I done to get this sorted:

- Install the sybase client tool (12.5
  in my case)
- I installed them in a directory
  c:\opt instead of default "c:\Program
  Files" to avoid space in path and
  also a shorter path
- The final location is
  c:\opt\sybase-MDS
- Put c:\opt\sybase-MDS\bin and
  c:\opt\sybase-MDS\dll into the PATH
  variable
- Define a SYBASE env variable and
  points to C:\opt\sybase-MDS
- Prepare a sql.ini file in
  C:\opt\sybase-MDS\ini

Syntax is similar to this

```
[MyDB]

master=TCP,servername,port

query=TCP,servername,port
```

After these steps, you can bring up ASE isql and you will see "MyDB" in the Server drop down.